# How to get rid of bounty in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Me, being new to Skyrim, accidentally punched someone and received a bounty of 40. Then, I said "I would rather die than go to jail" to a guard, not knowing this would make everyone hate me and attack me. How can I fix this without resetting my game or anything like that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what were you *expecting* when you said "I'd rather die than go to jail"?

Comment: I did not know it would be every single stinking guard set out for my blood.

Comment: Yes, it's obvious that you didn't expect it, I was asking what you *did* expect would happen? Did you expect they'd just say "Oh, okay, if that's how you feel about it." and let you go?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to get rid of a bounty:

1. Pay the fine when confronted by a guard.
2. Go to jail. Serve your time and your bounty shall be cleared.
3. If you resist arrest you can choose to yield during the fight (which brings you back to the menu where you must choose jail time or paying the fine), die, or you can escape from the guards that are attacking you and later pay the bounty.

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bounty_(Skyrim)